# Syncing videos in separate clients

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Two `video` players in **separate clients** are being synced by exchanging play/pause requests:

```
$(videoA).on("pause", e => sendRequestToPauseVideoB());
$(videoA).on("play", e => sendRequestToPlayVideoB());

$(videoB).on("pause", e => sendRequestToPauseVideoA());
$(videoB).on("play", e => sendRequestToPlayVideoA());
```

When the respective video receives a request to play or pause, it will call `video.play()` or `video.pause()`, respectively.

**The problem**

When videoA is paused, it will pause videoB, which **will then try to pause VideoA**.

This *usually* works fine, but suppose videoA pauses, sending a request for videoB to pause, but meanwhile videoB has played, sending a request for videoA to play.

Thus there is a *pause request* incoming to videoB and a *play request* incoming to videoA, which will in turn result in both videos switching (play/pause) state and **telling the other to change to this new state, resulting in an infinite loop**.

[image: Example]

**Why it happens**

Essentially, if a video receives a *play/pause request*, it should **not** send a *play/pause request* back to the other video.

Would it be possible for a video, within the *on Play* and *on Pause* event to deduce **if that event was due to a request**? Or somehow preventing the *play/pause event* from firing at all when a *request* calls `video.play()` or `video.pause()`?

Do you have any good solutions to this?

Comment: such logic would need to be written by **you**

Comment: Where's the logic that handles the requests (and alters the video state)?

Comment: Try `console.log(e)` to see whether the event has any useable information about its origin